# Is it possible to get ui api Picklist Value Collection response body in ltgn comp js (for pcklst dependencies)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, dependent-picklist, ui-api

Is it possible to access the [picklist value collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_picklist_values_collection.htm) response body in a custom component js using a built in [component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm)? I need access to the dependent picklist values and their *validFor* property.  I'm using the onload function of lightning:recordEditForm to get all the field values of a record without having to do anything server side like this:

componentController.js

```
var payload = event.getParams().recordUi;
var flds = payload.objectInfo.fields
```

From everything I've searched for and read I can't find a way of getting to the picklist value collection through the [RecordUi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_record_ui.htm) response body.

Is it possible to do something like that lighting:recordEditForm call and access the picklist value collection response body?  The information has to be somewhere because if you use lightning:inputField within the lighting:recordEditForm your dependent picklists function correctly...

Ultimately I need to get to the information that looks like this:

```
"picklistFieldValues" : {
    "Cities__c" : {
  "controllerValues" : {
    "Australia" : 0,
    "Brazil" : 1,
    "China" : 2,
    "Colombia" : 3,
  },
  "defaultValue" : null,
  "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/ui-api/object-info/account/picklist-values/012000000000000AAA/Cities__c",
  "values" : [ {
    "attributes" : null,
    "label" : "Cali",
    "validFor" : [ 3 ],
    "value" : "Cali"
  }, {
    "attributes" : null,
    "label" : "Chicago",
    "validFor" : [ 0 ],
    "value" : "Chicago"
  }, {
    "attributes" : null,
    "label" : "Dakar",
    "validFor" : [ 1 ],
    "value" : "Dakar"
  },]
},
```

So I can build strings of valid nested combinations for an end user search (essentially make it so they can search for a nested value and select all field values at once).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, via the onload event of the lightning:recordEditForm  (as you are currently doing),

access the `recordUI` Object:

```
JSON.stringify(event.getParam("recordUi"))
```

in the console you will see all your picklist values alongisde dependencies.

to access the picklist values:

```
event.getParam("recordUi").picklistValues.Fieldname.values
```

(be carefull, javascript is CAse Sensitive)

Comment: omg, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I tried reading through the recordUi output but it was 2mil lines and ctrl+f wasn't working all that great.

Comment: Took me a while to get to it as well when I had done the same a while back

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this behaviour is changed with recordEditForm since the picklistvalues are not coming in the onLoad event. There is a separate call being made to get the picklist values and i dont think we can access to that event.